# Is there a way to modify a live Calendar event through Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Goal: Add attendees through Google Calendar Add on to live event being created on the spot

Context: Live Event being created (left)+ Calendar Add on (Right)

[image: Live Event being created (left)+ Calendar Add on (Right)]

Code snip:

```
current_user = e.calendar.calendarId;
event_id = e.calendar.id;
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(current_user);
var event = calendar.getEventById(event_id);
```

However, when I open an event, and `current_user` and `event_id` have values, `event` seems to be `null`, because this event is not technically 'created' yet. If it were created yet, then a simple `event.addGuest()` would work

Is it even possible to customize a live event while it is being created? Every example I find only updates events already created.

**Edit**: Forgot to post scopes I am using. Snippet of appsscript.json is below

```
{
  ....,
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.current.event.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.current.event.write",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds"
  ],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      ...
      }
    },
    "calendar": {
      "currentEventAccess": "READ_WRITE",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so.  I wouldn't waste my time.  But I don't know for sure.  Why not go ahead and try it and let us know if it worked or not.

Comment: It doesn't work and I think you are right that Google hasn't implemented such logic yet.

Comment: I don't think they want you to have any direct interaction with their code.

Comment: The documentation [Workspace Calendar Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#calendar_event_object)  For anyone who reads this question and wants to see the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
  if (!e.calendar.capabilities.canAddAttendees) {
    return;
  }

  CardService.newCalendarEventActionResponseBuilder()
    .addAttendees(["example1@example.com", "example2@example.com"])
    .build();
```

See documentation at:
https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/calendar/calendar-actions?hl=en#adding_attendees_with_a_callback_function

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I do have a further question if you don't mind. So, i have noticed that when you have the add on viewed and you add a attendee (either through the code you shared or manually), it will actually refresh the calendar add on to the home page (leaving from the page it was on). What weird to me is that currently the triggers I have are these:
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomePage_noevent"
      },
      "eventOpenTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomePage"
      }

Why when an attendee is added, "onHomePage" pops up again?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the answer to your extra question.  I'd need to research it.  You could ask another question either here on SO, or on the [Apps Script Group](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community)